# Failing when deploying into a testnet

Tags: solidity, blockchain, python, infura

when I run brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network rinkeby I get this result:[image]

and this is my python code:

```
from brownie import accounts, config, SimpleStorage, network
def deploy_simple_storage():
 account = get_account()
simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
print(stored_value)
transaction = simple_storage.store(15, {"from": account})
transaction.wait(1)
updated_stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
print(updated_stored_value)
def get_account():
if network.show_active() == "development":
return accounts[0]
else:
return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
def main():
deploy_simple_storage()
```

-now this python code should make a state change to a smart contract from 0 to 15 on a rinkbey testnet and there is no error in my python code or in my solidity code and I have created a .env file so brownie could see my private key and my project ID on infura.
this is my .env file
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

The first thing I want to mention is that Rinkeby was deprecated about a month ago, so you won't be able to interact with it.

Make sure that you use the Goerli or Sepolia testnet!

Checkout this article [about the merge and testnets](https://chainstack.com/merge-a-step-by-step-guide-for-developers/) where you can see which testnets have been deprecated :)

Then here you can find a sample code to deploy and interact with a contract if you need it.

```py
from brownie import accounts, SimpleStorage

def main():
    # fetch the account
    account = accounts[0]

    # deploy contract
    deploy_contract = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from":account})

    # print contract address
    print(f"contract deployed at {deploy_contract}")

    # store a number
    transaction_receipt = deploy_contract.storeNumber(15,{"from":account})

    # wait for transaction confirmation
    transaction_receipt.wait(1)

    # retrieve the number
    retrieved_number = deploy_contract.readNumber()

    # print the retrieved number
    print(f"Number Retrieved : {retrieved_number}")
```

You can also check this article, where you can find an in depth [tutorial about Brownie and how to deploy and test](https://chainstack.com/the-brownie-tutorial-series-part-2/).

Chainstack provides reliable Goerli nodes if you need one:

#### Set up the endpoint URL

1. [Sign up with Chainstack](https://console.chainstack.com/user/account/create).
2. [Deploy a node](https://docs.chainstack.com/platform/join-a-public-network).
3. [View node access and credentials](https://docs.chainstack.com/platform/view-node-access-and-credentials).